Error in finding performance metrics in Quantization model
I'm working on Different Quantization methods,  can anyone tell me code to find Differentperformance metrics (e.g Precision,  recall, f1 score, accuracy) for those Quantized model( I.e fp16, dynamic range, full integer) and all these model are saved with .tflite.
I'm getting error When trying to find those values....
